# Using SQL to determine if all records of a related table have the same value

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that will update a record on one table depending on certain values in a related table:

MainTable contains a status field and is related to SubTable which also has a status field. I need to update the status of each record in MainTable where ALL of the related records in SubTable has the same status x. I've tried several queries but think I am going about it the wrong way. Any assistance would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are your tables linked by `status` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example having following tables :

```
   Producer ( Code,Name,Status)
   Goods    ( GCode,PCode( Producer Code),Name,Status)
```

and Query :

```
Update   Producer  set Status=F  
where not exists (select * from Goods where Status <> X and Goods.PCode= Producer.Code)
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to be what I'm after! I just want to do some more tests to make sure!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Update schema.yourtable s set s.fieldtoupdate = (
Select e.Relationalfield from schema.RealtionalTable  e where e.STATUSFIELD = s.STATUSFIELD);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks Stanley, I've tried your query but not getting it to work. I tried it like this (had to tweak a bit due to errors from the query window):

`Update MainTable
SET MainTable.Status= (
Select e.SubTableStatus
from SubTable e 
where e.SubTableStatus= 11);`

basically, if all the records in SubTable.SubTableStatus is 11, MainTable.Status must be set to 9.

Error given is: 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'

Comment: Are you saying that Status field is not a Unique value? For this to work the Status field will have to be a unique value

Comment: Nope, status is not unique, but I did get a what i was after, thanks. I do however have a different problem which your code helps with.

Comment: Aah OK Am glad you could get help.